# Recess Framework get parameter

Tags: url, query-string, recess

I'm using the recess framework. Suppose I have a URL like this

```
www.example.com/try.php?this=5
```

In recess, what do i do to access the value of parameter `this` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->request->get['this'];
```

Those variables {->get[], ->post[]} populate no matter what verb is being used.